# Copy cell value from one sheet and paste into another sheet after lookup

Tags: excel, vba

Here is what i need to do

1. I need to copy cell value from, D6 to column j in a different workbook,
2. Search for value in D2 in column B of a different workbook
3. If there is a match in column B, paste the value of D6 in same row but in j column.

Below is the code i have written, but seeing a compile error.

```
Sub Copy_Click()

Dim SearchStock As String
Dim EdgeScore As Integer
SearchStock = Workbooks("Checklist_Test").Worksheets("Screening_Dashboard").Range("D2").Value
EdgeScore = Workbooks("Checklist_Test").Worksheets("Screening_Dashboard").Range("D6").Value
EdgeScore.Copy

Workbooks("Test").Worksheets("Universe").Range("B:B").Find(SearchStock).Offset(0, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code located in one of these workbooks (in which one)? What are the file extensions of the workbooks (`.xlsx`, `.xlsm`, `.xlsb`)? On which row does the data in sheet `Universe` start? Are you expecting *EdgeScore* to be a whole number between `-32768` and `32767` (*Integer*)? You're getting the compile error because the *Copy* method is used with objects (worksheets, ranges...), not with 'simple' values like numbers, strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `Find` function using a `Range` object, and then trap the possible outcome if `Find` was not successful.

***Modified Code***

```
Sub Copy_Click()

Dim SearchStock As String
Dim EdgeScore As Long
Dim FindRng As Range

SearchStock = Workbooks("Checklist_Test").Worksheets("Screening_Dashboard").Range("D2").Value
EdgeScore = Workbooks("Checklist_Test").Worksheets("Screening_Dashboard").Range("D6").Value

Set FindRng = Workbooks("Test").Worksheets("Universe").Range("B:B").Find(SearchStock)
If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' confirm Find was able to find the values in "D2"
    ' paste value in "D6" to same row where Find was successful in column J
    Workbooks("Test").Worksheets("Universe").Range("J" & FindRng.Row).Value = EdgeScore
End If
    
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, when using Find, you need to specify some of the parameters,  else you may get unexpected results.   [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) under Remarks